# How to pass condition in a relation?

Tags: php

I have User model where I have multiple designation for people

User table looks like this

```
id | username | email | password | designation
```

**Project Model** contains

```
Project Name | Client Id | Project_Manager_id | delivery_manager_id
```

**Client Model** contains

```
id | client name |
```

**Task Model** contains

```
id | Project id | Task_Assign_employees_id
```

Here I am storing multiple employees for a single project those who have designations like Software Engineers, Senior Software Eng, etc.

Now, my question is, how can I create a relation between these models? Is it a required condition in Laravel relation ?

I need to retrieve project names along with project manager names, delivery manager names, client names and task assigned employees' names.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extra model when I was in that kind of situation.

**ProjectEmployee**

`id | project_id | employee_id`

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it does the job.

**EDIT:** And that's why you have the Task model

It's a many-to-many relation. You can use the `hasManyThrough()` relationship: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through.

> i need to retrive project name with project manager name , delivery manager name ,client name and task assigned employees name

You have to create the following functions:

In the **User** model:

```
public function projects()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('Project', 'Task');
}
```

In the **Project** model:

```
public function users()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('User', 'Task');
}

public function projectManager()
{
     return $this->hasOne('User', 'Project_Manager_id');
}

public function deliveryManager()
{
     return $this->hasOne('User', 'Deliver_Manager_id');
}

public function client()
{
     return $this->hasOne('Client', 'Client_id');
}
```

Now let's say you need to find a Project with `id` of 4.

`$project = Project::find(4);`

Now you need all the employees names.

```
foreach($project->users as $user){
    echo $user->name;
}
```

Now you need the delivery manager's name.

`$project->deliveryManager->name`

You might ask, why do we use `$project->users` without parentheses if we have the function users(). `$project->users()` return the relationship object and `$project->users` return the collection of users.

If you have any more questions, first read about the relationships here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships and look at the examples I gave you. If you have some more questions, feel free to comment here.

Comment: .yes same table in my case it is Task Model

Comment: .thank you.but i am not much familiar with hasmanythorgh.can you able to give more detail answer for my requirement.

Comment: .my problem is with hasManyThrough.i cant retrieve data

Comment: What does it retrieve then?

Comment: now i solver my problem but still i have one problem .if i use  $data=Project::find(1)->with('clients','projectManager'->get(); then it retrieve all record .if i add first() instead of get() then it retrieve table first record.only if i use where instead of find then its proper

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: display all detail based on project id